# removing the duplicating code code from cell delegate

Tags: swift, generics, delegates, delegation, redundancy

I have a tableview, to configure a cell (from VC),

```
cell.model = dataSource[indexpath.row]
```

In the didSet of cell.model, I am initialising the cell contents.
Cell has 3 buttons, tapping on which, I am informing the VC through CellDelegate

```
protocol CellDelegate {
    func didTapButton1(model: Model)
    func didTapButton2(model: Model)
    func didTapButton3(model: Model)
}
```

**My concern:-**
I don't want to pass the model here (as it is already associated with the Cell - somehow need to fetch the model from cell)
I would like to call didTapButton() without the parameter. Then in the VC,

```
extension VC: CellDelegate {
//I need to fetch the model associated with the cell.
    func didTapButton1() { }
    func didTapButton2() { }
    func didTapButton3() { }
}
```

I could achieve this using closure, but it is not preferred here.
Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the model parameter? What about having only one function in the delegate - `didTapButton(model:buttonNumber:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason why you don't want to pass the model is because having a `model` in all three methods look like code duplication. Well, if you have look at the delegates in the framework, such as `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITextFieldDelegate`, most, if not all, of them accept the thing that they are a delegate of as the first parameter. All the methods in `UITableViewDelegate` has a `tableView` parameter. Therefore, it would be OK for you to follow the pattern as well:

```
protocol CellDelegate {
    func didTapButton1(_ cell: Cell)
    func didTapButton2(_ cell: Cell)
    func didTapButton3(_ cell: Cell)
}
```

Personally, I would write only one method in this delegate:

```
protocol CellDelegate {
    func didTapButton(_ cell: Cell, buttonNumber: Int)
}
```

In the VC extension, you simply check `buttonNumber` to see which button is pressed:

```
switch buttonNumber {
    case 1: button1Tapped()
    case 2: button2Tapped()
    case 3: button3Tapped()
    default: fatalError()
}

// ...

func button1Tapped() { ... }
func button2Tapped() { ... }
func button3Tapped() { ... }
```

Comment: if there is only 1 method, can I use closure callback for more simplicity?

Comment: A VC might have 2 tableviews, to differentiate delegates have the tableview parameter in the delegate

Comment: I still didn't get supporting point for why we have to send the parameter? - apple framework have the reason, but why we should?

Comment: @Nagaraj you want the model right? Having a cell parameter allows you to get the model.